# How to change the value in an object when using useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning React so far I'm having a problem when I want to click on the Vote button and the vote for that story increases. Can someone guide me?

JavaScript code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const anecdotes = [
  "If it hurts, do it more often",
  "Adding manpower to a late software project makes it later!",
  "The first 90 percent of the code accounts for the first 90 percent of the development time...The remaining 10 percent of the code accounts for the other 90 percent of the development time.",
  "Any fool can write code that a computer can understand. Good programmers write code that humans can understand.",
  "Premature optimization is the root of all evil.",
  "Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place. Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by definition, not smart enough to debug it."
];

function Button(props) {
  return <button onClick={props.event}>{props.text}</button>;
}

function App() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(0);
  const [points, setPoints] = useState({
    0: 0,
    1: 0,
    2: 0,
    3: 0,
    4: 0,
    5: 0
  });

  function next() {
    setSelected(Math.floor(Math.random() * anecdotes.length));
  }

  function vote() {

  }

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Anecdote of the day</h1>
      <p>{anecdotes[selected]}</p>
      <p>has {points[selected]} votes</p>
      <Button text="Vote" event={vote} />
      <Button text="Next anecdote" event={next} />
    </>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Thank you.

Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-b6-usestate-type-2-05q8x

Comment: It's better if you can post the code along with the question.

Comment: @XPD Just copied from codesandbox.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply in the `vote` function clone the original object with spread syntax first, by doing this you will have a new object called `newPoints`. Then you need to update the selected one by adding `newPoints[selected] + 1` to increase the vote numbers. Then it is ready to update with `setPoints`.

Something like this:

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState(0);

const vote = () => {
   const newPoints = {...points};
   newPoints[selected] = newPoints[selected] + 1;
   setPoints(newPoints);
}
```

Read further here: [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you. I have solved the problem. But it seems that this problem can be solved with Computed Property Names. Can you help me one more time?

Comment: @Thien Could you please help me to understand better? How do you want to use computed property in this case? Thank you!

Comment: I have solved this problem with: setPoints ({
      ... points, [selected]: points [selected] + = 1
    }) .Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This should be able to do the trick.

```
function vote() {
    let p = {...points};
    p[selected] += 1;
    setPoints(p);
    console.log( points);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I think the most important thing which everyone is missing here is

   ```
   setPoints( points => {
       //new Points 
       return newPoints})
   ```

   if you set a state from previous value then you need to pass a
   function for setState to avoid race cases.
2. If the state is an object then there is no use of mutating it since the reference will be the same old one and react does not rerender.

   To solve this issue generally what I do is

   ```
   setPoints( points => {
       let newPoints = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(points));
       //change newPoints; 
       return newPoints
   })
   ```

   The main reason why I go with `JSON.parse(JSON.stringiy(points))` rathar than `{...points}` is because in deeply nested objects the inner objects will also be new objects.